# Google Sheet REGEXMATCH with range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to search specific text in an entire column, the text to be searched is in another column. I am using below formula:

=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",IFERROR(if(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(A2:A), B2:B4),"Yes","No"),"Not Found")))

This function is comparing cell A2 with B2, A3 with B3 and so on.... I want to compare A2 with B2:B4, A3 with B2:B3...

Below is the sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/164kxDO9aWZzr5qXjvtRlk_tiRoKU1W7Xc-Ig9VH8qzE/edit#gid=495498161

Any help on above will be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1):

Change your formula to

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",IFERROR(if(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(A2:A), TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B4)),"Yes","No"),"Not Found")))
```

Or, in case you want an exact match:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",IFERROR(if(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(A2:A), ".*"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:B4)&".*"),"Yes","No"),"Not Found")))
```

Also see the duplicated sheet in the spreadsheet you shared.

See if that works?

Comment: Hello.... the formula are working and giving the result, is it possible to make the formula bit simple by using SEARCH as below : =ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",if(iserror(SEARCH($B$2:$B$5,A2:A)),"No","Yes"))).. I had added sheet named "Search" for reference

Comment: You can try =ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A2:A),"",if(iserror(match(A2:A, $B$2:$B$5, 0)),"No","Yes")))

Comment: The formula worked but it identifies only specific text i.e. if the cell contains ABC then its will reflect yes but if the cell contains XYZABC or ABC XYZ it will reflect No

Comment: Check the formula in F2 . It produces the same output as the formula with regexmatch.